# To get a null value if data is not present in the table

Tags: sql, if-statement, null, where-clause, union

```
select number2, number3
from table3
where acc_num3 = 1234
union
select number2, null as number3
from table2
where acc_num2 = 1234
```

I have a query as above, I need an output as null if the number mentioned (in where condition)is not present in either of the tables

I am getting the o/p for the above query correctly, but when i try a number that is not present in either of tables I need to get an o/p as null, null... but i am getting only column names and no data

Comment: Please show sample input of all affected tables, the expected outcome of the query and explain the entire logic, not one single case only. You should also tag your DBMS.

Comment: This is a sql db, the table 2 contains columns such as account category and account number, similarly does table 3, and everytime i search a account number i need to fetch the acc_category from table 3, if data not present then it has to fetch the acc category from table2, so far i am able to execute.. But when the asked account number does not exist in either of the table, i need an o/p as null

Comment: Please read and follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, don't abuse comments to improve your question, but edit it.